# Is it possible cache password protected content in a web app for use in an offline web app (iOS / Android)?

Tags: android, ios, html, web-applications, mobile

Essentially here is the scenario:

- I have a mobile web app
- The web app has next to no content publicly available but has a login system
- Upon logging in the user is given access to specific pages according to their preferences

**What I want to do:**

Allow offline caching of the web app and continue to serve the custom content according to the user logged in (yes obviously the data will be cached and the user would have needed to have logged in at least once before).

**The problem:**

*** *Edited***

Basically I want to be able to access the same data I could after logging in online, offline, however when accessing the web app offline there will be no password protection.  I am hoping/assuming that by using the manifest file I can get the the mobile browser to cache the data I would be seeing as a logged in user, and then with no password requirement redisplay this to me when offline?

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just writing an answer as I have found it to be possible.

Essentially the solution is not to include a manifest file on the login page (or homepage) of the site.  Once logged in (lets call this the landing page) a manifest file is then served, which will then allow caching of "protected" pages.

When the user is offline, the webapp checks to see if it online (client side), if it is offline it will redirect to the websites landing page (mentioned above) bypassing the login screen and serving cached content.

In addition, I mentioned users are shown specific content depending on preferences - this has been achieved by using a dynamic manifest file - so different users' browsers get are told to cache different pages :)  It was a huge pain to set up but seems to be working well for some time now.

As the data is cached it is not necessarily 100% secure but as mentioned above, if the user has logged in on a particular device before, then they are able to to view the content offline without the need to login again - this level of security was enough for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Caching is only capable of storing the client side part of your webapp, but the login mechanism and the validation is in the server side code. The client side will never remember the previously entered values.

If you want to use your services from a mobile device in offline code, than you will have to write a mobile application wich stores the credentials and the data.

Comment: Is there no way to use the cache to store a users login details (as they are logging in to the site) and using that possibly to encrypt the stored data in the cache (offline webpages)... then when logging in (offline) using the credentials to decrypt the cache - therefore there is no real login process however content is still served to correct login details? Maybe am way ahead of myself here with the capabilities of mobile caching / local storage :(

Comment: No. You have no such control over the web browser's caching mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response!  So failing all that then I'm guessing it would be possible to at least cache the custom content when logged in to the web app and then serve it when offline (with no data protection/authentication of course)? :S

Comment: If you want to use it from a browser, than you can't tell whether it will work or not. As I said, you have no control over the caching. You should forget this scenario altogether. If you want offline mode from mobile devices, than write an application for that.

Comment: Sorry I'm getting a bit confused because if we cannot rely on the cache then we can't have a mobile web app right?  Can we not occasionally update the manifest file etc so the most recent version of a web app is saved offline? Sorry you're losing me a bit with the last one...

Comment: Just to note the pages in my web app are not highly dynamic (although there is a CMS) however it is more about restricting pages for specific users

Comment: It doesn't matter. The browser might empty it's cache anytime if the device is low on disk space, or otherwise. The user might have turned off cahcing altogether. Even if you have a static page, it is still bad practice and very unsure. Trying to build a function around this won't work.

Comment: I agree with most of what you have said so far but essentially it sounds like you are knocking offline web apps as a whole.. my question is based around offline web apps and how to best implement what I am trying to achieve, not whether it is a viable to even try to build an offline web app as this is already the path I am going down... There are many successful, complicated and detailed web apps out there (take the FT web app for example)...

Comment: Javascript won't remember the previously entered values in the fields, unless you hardcode them into the js itself. You can't access any database, and you can't cache database values for offline use in client side code. You can have static HTML pages with javascript effects, or some funcionality, but you won't be able to use anything else. Maybe 1 user in every 10 will be able to look at the cached page, but for what purpose? I can't understand. They won't be able to make any changes. If you are writing a javascript calculator, or something of this caliber, than i think it is ok.

Comment: I have updated my question to exclude login options, the web app essentially when offline is serving static content and requires no interaction other than the user can read a certain paragraph on a page when they have no access to the internet - I thought this was the exact purpose of this technology and could be relied upon to some extent :S  I have given you a vote up for sending me in the right direction :)